# Spring injection tricks

Tags: java, spring

**I have:** injecting `MyClass` and `String` objects into `Utils` at constructor.

**Questions:**

1. How does it works when in Utils bean definition (look at *beans definition* section) I mentioned only the second argument of `Utils` constructor?
2. How to pass `MyClass` mock into `Utils` object in unit tests? I mean how to redefine the bean definition?

*Utils.java*

```
public class Utils {
    @Inject
    public Utils(MyClass obj, String val) {
        this.obj = obj;
        this.val = val;
    }
```

*Beans definition:*

```
<bean class="com.mypack.MyClass"/>

<bean id="utils" class="com.mypack.Utils">
    <constructor-arg value="bucket" />
</bean>
```

Comment: If you do a unit test just do `new Utils(new MockMyClass(), "La-di-da")` and test like a boss.

Comment: @Bart the `Utils` is in another subproject, so I can't just pass that object as an argument. I think I need to use test context in my unit tests, and redefine `MyClass` bean there

Comment: @V_B You are exactly right, you should redefine the bean (with a "dummy" behavior, or whatever) in your test context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define define another(test) context for the unit tests:

```
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @ContextConfiguration(locations = { "my-test-context.xml",
                                        "some-other-context.xml" })
    public class SkipSampleFunctionalTests {

        @Autowired
        private SomeBean bean;

    ...
    }
```

If you want to override only one bean, you can import your main(core) context int the test context and change only the desired bean:

```
<import resource="main-context.xml"/>
<bean id="x" class="com.asd.MyClass">
     <property name="y" ref="y"/>
</bean>
```